# Increse endpoint in USB CDC ACM

Tags: usb, cdc

Can we increase end points in usb cdc acm. Currently i have 1 endpoint for notification(interrupt) and two endpoints for IN and OUT of data. I want one more interrput based endpoint.

Comment: Please share the reason why you want one more interrupt endpoint? Are you in host mode or device mode? If host, then I do not see how its possible as end points are physical buffers in the device and you can't increase it just like that. If you are device like some micro controller, then maybe you can simulate endpoint using your firmware and multiplex the data using a single available physical endpoint.

Comment: im device and i want to send some aysncronous data to host in addition to regulat data in and out.